# n.slice() is not a function in geolib node js

Tags: javascript

this  is the error if u have any idea help :

TypeError: n.slice is not a function at Module.K (E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\geolib\lib\index.js:1:9921)
at E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\server.js:440:38
at E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:697:5
at handleCallback (E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:102:55)
at E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:840:66
at E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:697:5
at E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:925:9
at Cursor._endSession (E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\cursor.js:397:7)
at E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:923:12
at maybePromise (E:\USERS\DELL\Project fullstack\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:685:3)

```
The code :
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

    app.post('/Commander', (req, res) => {
        var command = req.cookies["Command"];
        command = JSON.parse(command);
        command = command.Command;
        var Info = req.body;
        console.log("command->", command)
        console.log('Info : ', Info)
    
        CommandDB = {
            UserName: Info.UserName,
            Email: Info.Email,
            Phone: Info.Phone,
            command: command,
            Stat: "Confirming",
            Location: Info.Location,
            Adresse: Info.Adresse
        }
        // Getting the distance between the client position and the delivery guy pos
        db.getDB().collection(Livreurs).find({}).toArray((err, livrs) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }
            else {
                //  console.log(livrs)
                for (var i = 0; i < livrs.length; i++) {
                    var livrs_pos = livrs[i].Location;
                }
                console.log(livrs_pos)
                var orderByDist = geolib.orderByDistance(CommandDB.Location, livrs_pos);
                console.log(orderByDist)
                // Insert the Command
                db.getDB().collection(Commands).insertOne(CommandDB, (err, resu) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Element inserted ! ', resu.insertedCount, resu.insertedId);
                        //  res.redirect('/Command_Info');
                    }
                })
                console.log("CommandDB : ", CommandDB)
                var Command_Gest = livrs.Command_Gest
                Command_Gest.push(resu.insertedId)
                db.getDB().collection(Livreurs).updateOne({ Location: orderByDist[0] }, { $set: Command_Gest }, (err, liv_mod) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('GestCom inserted ', liv_mod)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        // 
    
    })
```

Comment: Hello, are you sure you attached the right code to problem description? Please give more details...

Comment: i just edited it and inserted all the details

Comment: Which of the lines is the 440 that the stack trace references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `var livrs_pos = livrs[i].Location` inside your `for` loop. Then you're trying to pass `livrs_pos` to `geolib.orderByDistance` (second argument). At this point, `livrs_pos` does not appear to be an array, which fails internally to geolib because `orderByDistance` calls `.slice()` on that array. Hence, `n.slice` is not a function, because `n` is not an array.

It looks like `livrs[i].Location` is an object instead. I think you should declare `var livrs_pos = [];` above your `for` loop. Then inside the loop do `livrs_pos.push(livrs[i].Location);`